# In dust.js, can you pass a parameter from a sub-template through to a base?

Tags: dust.js

In my dust template library, have a 3 levels of templates:

base: `{#myparam}{.}{/myparam}`

parent: `{>base}`

child: `{>parent myparam="value"}`

How might I pass myparam from 'child' to the 'base' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
{! base template !}
{myparam}
```

then

```
{! parent template !}
{>base myparam=childparam/}
```

then

```
{! child template !}
{>parent childparam="value"/}
```

Try this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smfoote/gZM3H/1/

Comment: @smfoote, Im learning dust. Can you please let me know how to pass an array instead of a string. If i pass an array its treated as an string. If i remove the double quoted to pass it as an array im getting an error. Here is what i tried. http://jsfiddle.net/gZM3H/5/

Comment: Can you ask this is a separate question, and add a code example there?